# How to get data from a cell in DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Hello I have a Data Grid That have columns that have check box. I would like to disable the check box on a certain condition. I have a SQL DB that I get from it a DataSet then I fill the data set inside the Data Grid. Here is some of my code

```
    Dim loopRow As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim ColDS As New DataColumn("Status")
        ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add(ColDS)
        For loopval As Integer = 0 To loopRow
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(loopval)(8).ToString = "True" Then
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(loopval)(11) = "Confirmed"
            Else
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(loopval)(11) = "Pending"
            End If
        Next
        For loopDate As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(loopDate)("ProgramTours_FromDate") <= Now.Date Then

            End If
        Next
        GrdAgentBL.DataSource = ds
        GrdAgentBL.DataBind()
```

Comment: The condition is the Tour From Date if it's less than now date then it will disable a column called Confirmed in the data grid which it has a check box inside it. I need that column disabled if it's meet the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a solution for your query.

```
//I am setting dataTable using this function  
Private Sub setDataTable()
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        dt.Columns.Add("Val")
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr("Name") = "Abcd"
        dr("Val") = 1
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("Name") = "xyz"
        dr("Val") = 2
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        grdView.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        grdView.DataSource = dt
        grdView.DataBind()

    End Sub

// This code will do enabling or disabling the checkbox.
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView grdRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (grdRow.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString() == "1")
            {
                e.Row.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

***best practice*** : Please form your datatable from SQL. using a simple case and exclude this loop in your code. So if there may be a 1000 rows, u need to iterate 1000.

```
select val1,val2,(case when val1=0 then 1 else 0 end) as val3 from tbl.
```

So this may works faster than any iteration

Comment: This is a good answer but I will provide you with another one

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
 For Each Item As DataGridItem In GrdAgentBL.Items 'load the items first
                Dim lblTemp As New Label 'My Data is stored in a label
                lblTemp = Item.Cells(2).Controls(1) 'So I take it inside that new label
                Dim tx As String = lblTemp.Text 'Then I load it on the Tx var
                If tx <= Now.Date Then 'if it's meet the condition we will disable the column
                    Item.Cells(11).Enabled = False
                End If
 Next
```

Comment: if this is the case why can't you compare this value and get a bool value from db? There functions like Getdate() etc which returns today's date. So based on the condition you can simply enable or disable the grid.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am not sure about when these lines will execute. will update you after some findings

Comment: may i know what is the difference between using rawdatabound and your method ?

Comment: First I have the data in a dataset so I don't want to connect to the data base again. in the dataset I have all the values I need so I don't need to get another data. These lines execute when the value of a column in the grid meet the condition. the column have a date and the date tell if the person can cancel in that time.

Comment: but if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow).. code you need to write in Rawdatabound method . So that it will check the condition and builds the raw. It will call automatically for all rows after the ` grdView.DataBind()`. So if I follow your way, you are using a separate iteration to check condition and fill the data.

Comment: that is correct, I check the data from inside the data grid then I apply the business logic.